# Accents not positioned correctly over rsfs letters

Tags: math-mode, accents

On my computer, the file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

$\tilde{\mathscr M}$

\end{document}
```

renders as

[image]

But shouldn't the tilde be shifted to the right, so that it's directly above the top points of the M? (I have similar problems with other accents and other rsfs letters.)

What files do you think I need to update? My .log file says I'm using

mathrsfs 1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)
ursfs.fd 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)

Edit: Here is my ursfs.fd file:

```
%% ursfs.fd
%%
%% (c) Copyleft 1995, 1996, 1998, 1999 J"org Knappen
%% Licence: GNU public licence version 2
%%
\ProvidesFile{ursfs.fd}[1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)]
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{%
   <5> <6> rsfs5
   <7> rsfs7
   <8> <9> <10> <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> rsfs10
}{}
\endinput

J"org Knappen, Barbarossaring 43, D-55118 Mainz, Allemagne
Author of the Book: Schnell ans Ziel mit LaTeX2e, Oldenbourg-Verlag
M"unchen, 1997, ISBN 3-486-24199-0.
% /ursfs.fd
```

Edit #2: Okay, I think the problem is with the rsfs10.tfm file that my MiKTeX looks at by default. I downloaded a rsfs10.tfm file from a website and put the file in the same directory as my test paper, and the `$\tilde{\mathscr M}$` rendered correctly.

Is there a preferred website to get .tfm files from?

Comment: I have the same files and the output has the tilde in the correct position. Can you add the contents of the file `ursfs.fd`?

Comment: My `rsfs10.tfm` file has size 688 bytes, found in `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/rsfs/rsfs10.tfm` Can you check for it?

Comment: You should file a bug report to the MiKTeX maintainer. If you download the tfm files from CTAN they should be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my system (TeX Live 2012) the output is correct. This seems a problem in the determination of the "skewchar"; if the `ursfs.fd` file says

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
```

then the problem is almost certainly in a corrupted TFM file. Here's the output of `ls -l` on the relevant directory:

```bsh
$ ls -l /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/rsfs/
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  688 Dec 15  2008 rsfs10.tfm
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  684 Dec 15  2008 rsfs5.tfm
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  692 Dec 15  2008 rsfs7.tfm
```

On CTAN the fonts are only available as Metafont sources, but it's easy to produce the TFM files: just run

```bsh
mf "\mode=cx;input rsfs10"
```

and then test the good TFM file; then you can put it in the directory where the old one is. Repeat for `rsfs7` and `rsfs5`.

On Windows this should work in a command shell.